Can't enable SELinux on Ubuntu 24
I can't enable SELinux on Ubuntu 24 The only file under /etc/selinux is semanage.conf
All the posts I read said to edit /etc/selinux/configure but that file isn't present I was trying to install it so I could troubleshoot mail server fails to establish relay connection

you may find this Linux Capable post useful
